# MYSQL database schema to store game prerequisite information

Tags: mysql, database-design

The game has 5 skills a player can have like so:

```
Skills: Run, Jump, Shoot, Fly, Sleep
```

A player can have all skills, a subset or none. A player will have a value corresponding to each skill which will increase or decrease based on their performances. An example skill set for a player would be like so:

```
run: 30
jump: 87
Sleep: 2
```

Next, the game has 10 levels. Each level has a set of prerequisite skills a player needs to satisfy before being able to compete in. A level may also have as a prerequisite the completion of another level.

So for example level 5 may have the following prerequisites:

```
Level 5 requires: 10 Fly, 25 Sleep, 90 Run and completion of level 1,2,3
```

For my use case (given at the end) I have decided to store the prerequisite information in a MYSQL database. I can think of two approaches to store the above information:

**Approach 1:**

1. LEVELS table - Columns: ID, Level Name
2. SKILLS table - Columns: ID, Skill Name
3. SKILL_PREREQUISITE table- Columns: ID, LevelID, SkillID, requiredValue
4. LEVEL_PREREQUISITE - Columns: ID, LevelID, prerequisiteLevelID

**Approach 2:**

1. LEVELS table - Columns: ID, Level Name
2. LEVEL_SKILL table - Columns: ID, QuestID, Run, Fly, Sleep, Jump, Shoot
3. LEVEL_PREREQUISITE - Columns: ID, LevelID, prerequisiteLevelID

**My use case is as follows:**

given the skills of a player, and the levels they have completed, what are the levels that they are eligible to participate in?

Keeping this in mind, is approach 1, approach 2 or something completely different the most optimum solution for my problem? I am also open to suggestions that does not depend on MYSQL if that is the way forward!

Note: The player information (ie: Skill level, completed levels) is not in the database. Think of them as input parameters that will be used in the query to get the eligible levels for a player

Comment: Definitely not approach 2

Comment: Approach 1 seems like "over-normalization".  Why have "16" instead of "Sleep"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if your levels and skills are fixed, or if you plan to add later new levels and/or skills (or want to be at least opened to this possibility).

In the first case I think a very simple table will provide a good solution, assuming a numeric representation of the problem of this kind:

1. Skill: a skill 0 means the player does not have the skill (or if you consider 0 a valid skill, then -1 could mean no skill)
2. Level: 0 means not completed, 1 means completed.

In this case the prerequisite table could have sixteen attributes:

```
LevelID, RequiredRun, RequiredJump, RequiredShoot, RequiredFly, RequiredSleep, RequiredLevel1, RequiredLevel2,...,RequiredLevel10
```

and ten rows, so for instance the row corresponding to level 5 in your example is:

```
5 90 0 0 10 25 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If, on the other hand, you want to design something that can grow in the future, then your Approach 1 is the right way to go.